# how do we configure multiple pollers to send messages to one transformer

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How do i get multiple pollers of same type to route messages to a single transformer .I don't mind having the messages queued before the transformer

Comment: Please, be more specific and provide more info on the matter. The sample would be great too.

Comment: I am trying to poll three email boxes using three different IMAP inbound adapters .I have to process the emails - save the email content as a file  , and attachments into the filesystem . I have it working for one inbox . The si example was very helpful . I based my design on it . Now I need to do the same for emails picked up by three adapters . I wanted to an idea on the best way to design this in SI .

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you just want to reuse a message flow for all your `<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>`s. It's just enough to configure them all to the same `channel`.

Actually there is no difference with classical OOP design, when you inject the same service to different actions, like MVC controller, or JMS listeners.

But here we do exactly the same, but inject a `MessageChannel` to send results of those entry point to it and don't think what's going on underneath.

Please, read more books about `Enterprise Integration Patterns`

Comment: thanks artem. thats how i have it wired now. I was wondering if there is a better way to do it in spring integration . Is a channel by default capable of queueing up messages in case it is receiving a lot of messages simultaneously from different sources